# ADD-ADGroupMember at Random in 4 Groups from list of computers, with no repeats/duplicates between 4 groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory, activedirectorymembership

My code below is not able to take the " $groupname " list and run it in the ADD-ADGroupmember step. I tried a different way, but I still end up with a computer showing in different groups. All I want to do is add computers to a select number of groups at Random, and only allow each unique computer to be assigned to one group? Any ideas?

```
$logfile = "results-$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hhmmtt')).log"

Get-Date | Out-File $logfile

$groupnameprefix = "Automated"

$organizationalunitpath="OU paths go here. There are multiple"


$grouporganizationalunitpath = "OU paths for AD Security Groups go here"
$NumberofComputersPerGroup = "300"
# This is a list of computer names that will be used to generate group names
$Patch_Groups = @(
"_Group_1",
"_Group_2",
"_Group_3",
"_Group_4"
)

# Get all computers from the specified organizational unit
[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] $computers = $organizationalunitpath |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_ }

# Create the new group
foreach ($Patch_Group in $Patch_Groups){
# Generate the group name by concatenating the prefix and the Patch Group name with spaces removed
$groupname = $groupnameprefix + $Patch_Group.Replace(" ","")
try {
# Create the group using the generated name and the specified organizational unit path
New-ADGroup -Name $groupName -path $grouporganizationalunitpath -GroupScope Global -verbose
} 

catch { 
         $message = "ADGroup $groupName already exists"
            $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
            Write-Warning $message
            Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
            $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
 }


    try {
        $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups = Get-Random -input $computers -count 300
        $computers = $computers | where {$_ -notin $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups}
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Members $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups -verbose
    
    
    }
    catch {
        $message = ' A problem occurred trying to add Members'
        $message | Out-File $logfile -Append
        Write-Warning $message
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
        $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $logfile -Append
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, ignore what I wrote previously, I see what's happening now.

The Get-Random bit of your code isn't selecting a random Computer, it's just picking a random number and passing that down the pipeline.

Assuming $computers is no more complex than the equivalent of :

```
$computers=@()
$computers="computer1","computer2","computer3","computer4","computer5","computer6","computer7","computer8"
```

then this code will do the trick :

```
$AddComputerstoRandomADGroups = Get-Random -input $computers -count 4
$computers = $computers | where {$_ -notin $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups}
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupname -Members $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups -verbose
```

which in this instance, selects 4 computers at random from the 8 currently in $computers, then updates the $computers variable to equal everything in $computers EXCEPT those computers assigned to $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups so they don't get selected in future iterations.

Edit - if you're still not finding the script works I'd suggest you need to output what is actually happening to narrow down where your issue is. As an example, I took your code and stripped it down to the following, which works fine.

```
$organizationalunitpath="CN=Computers,DC=mydomain"
$Patch_Groups = @(
"_Group_1",
"_Group_2",
"_Group_3",
"_Group_4"
)
$groupnameprefix = "Automated"
[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] $computers = $organizationalunitpath |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $_ }
foreach ($Patch_Group in $Patch_Groups){
    $groupname = $groupnameprefix + $Patch_Group.Replace(" ","")
   # write-host "New Group - Groupname = $groupname - path = $oupath"
    $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups = Get-Random -input $computers -count 20
    $computers = $computers | where {$_ -notin $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups}
   # write-host "add to $groupname computer $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups"   
   write-host "-- computers"
   $computers.name 
   write-host "-- added computers"
   $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups.name 
   write-host "---"
}
```

Throughout each of the four iterations the number of entries within the $computers variable is reducing, so the specified number of machines are being selected at random, potentially added to the group, and then those computers are being removed from that list so they're no longer available to be returned, which you can also see from the output for $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups and I'm not seeing any machines multiple times in the four outputs for $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups.

So try running that and see what output you get, since you can try it and see what's going to be happening without actually creating groups and adding machines to them.

Comment: Okay. Updated. I am getting a strange error:

Comment: What can I do to make sure the groupname's are being passed in? Also when I check the groups no members are being added. Currently all at 0's
WARNING:  A problem occurred trying to add Members
WARNING: Cannot find an object with identity: '7' under: 'DC=domain,DC=com'.

WARNING: Cannot find an object with identity: '5' under: 'DC=domain,DC=com'.

WARNING: Cannot find an object with identity: '3' under: 'DC=consumercellular,DC=com'.

WARNING: Cannot find an object with identity: '8' under: 'DC=domain,DC=com'.

Comment: Aha, thanks for confirming that error, I'd misunderstood what was happening, but I see what the issue is now (and this time been able to test my code! :) )

Comment: Correct. There are 2 problems. The $groupname identity step and then ensuring the groups dont have the same exact members.

Comment: @user3911968 Cool, well hopefully my rewritten answer fixed the second part. For $groupname we could probably do with your question being updated to give us an idea of what $Patch_Groups and $groupnameprefix contain or how they're generated outside of your listed code, to work out why you're not ending up with a working $groupname... and of course what error you're now getting without $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups generating a load of numbers.

Comment: Updated my original code in question. When I test your updated answer code and increase the count to 300, I still find duplicates. There will be around 1100-1200 computers between the 4 groups, which will reside across the 4 AD security groups. I am not getting an error now on groupname.

Comment: Are none of the computers being removed from $computers or just some remaining? You could perhaps try outputting the value of $computers at the end to see if it still contains the complete list. If it is then while I'm not familiar with [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] specifically, you might also need to add that before $AddComputerstoRandomADGroups to make sure that's setup as the same data type.

Comment: $computers is working fine. The problem is, when the script starts to add the computers to the AD groups, It adds the computers to other groups. The Script needs to only add the computer 1 time, between the 4 groups, then move on to the next computer. " [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] " can be removed if need be. I just want the script to automatically grab the Computers from the OUs, assign it to one computer to one of the 4 groups and thats it.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but it shouldn't as the computers should no longer be in the list of computers available to be added. It should be selecting those 300 computers into a new variable, adding those computers to a group, and then removing those 300 from the original variable. So if that's not happening then I'd guess {$_ -notin isn't seeing the two lists as the same type or matching in some way to remove one from the other.

Comment: Correct. Is there any other method I can use to ensure the same computer is not used in multiple groups? How could I do a removal step?

Comment: @user3911968 OK, see my latest edit at the end of my reply and see if that helps track down where the issue is.